# Python subprocess pkill

Tags: python, subprocess, kill-process

I want to use `pkill -f myPattern` in a python's subprocess:

```
import subprocess as sp

def stop_process(name,host):
    host  = host.strip()
    if host == socket.gethostname():
         sp.call ([ 'pkill -f', name ]) 
    else:
         sp.call ([ 'ssh', host,  'pkill -f ' + name ])
```

when I call `stop_process` with all nodes in cluster, it works for all nodes but the current node. That is, when `host == socket.gethostname()` the application prints `Terminated` and exits.

Is it the right way to stop the process with given pattern? If yes, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could that be that in the first call you use a list while in the second you use  a string for the pkill command? Could I suggest you to try using shlex.split?

Comment: Are you sure that `host == socket.gethostname()` is `True`?

Comment: Yes, even without any if condition, it crashes. I tested with `os.system('pkill -f ' + name)`. Again, the application stops with `Terminated` message

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia In the simplest case  `sp.call ([ 'pkill -f', 'myPattern' ])` without any variables does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `sp.call ([ 'pkill', '-f', name ])`? The arguments might be split correctly up in the other case because it goes through ssh.

Comment: @J.P.Petersen thanks for answer. I get the following error:`  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception`

Answer (score 0):

When you start your python program you probably invoke it passing the name of the process to kill (just guessing here..).
`pkill` will find also this process (you use `-f`) and kill it before it terminates properly. You need to find a way to filter the pid of the python program (try `os.getpid()` for example), or use only the process name (avoiding the `-f` option).

It happens only in your local machine because only there you have the python program running.